# How would I go about showing category parent-child relationship in form field dropdown?

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child, categories

Currently, I'm working on a form for a wordpress site that has a field where a user can select categories. When the field is clicked or typed in, the categories appear in alphabetical order as can be seen in this [image](https://imgur.com/a/vEyltdT).

These categories have parent-child relationships, and I'd like to demonstrate that in the dropdown list. For example, `cat-4` in the image above is a child of `cat-1`, and so ideally `cat-4` will appear under its parent and have an indentation or dash before it. Is there any built in or standard way to achieve this in wordpress?

Comment: I would either use [optgroup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)s or create two separate dropdowns, one for the parent and the 2nd one will change based on the selection from the first. Also, your image appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `wp_dropdown_categories()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) appears to display hierarchical taxonomies, with child terms being indented according to their parent.

Comment: Hey, so you were right and this does exactly what I was hoping it would do, thanks! It might not be a perfect solution for my use case though as the extra functionality my team wants is to be able to type into the field and have suggestions pop up to match. 

Do you know if `wp_dropdown_categories` can be modded like that?

Comment: `wp_dropdown_categories()` by itself won't, but implementing a JS library like [Select2](https://select2.org/) with an existing dropdown would.

Comment: This worked perfectly with Select2, thanks.